# SQL query to get repeating column value that have other columns in a certain codition

Tags: sql

Let's say we have below table of below schema.

```
create table result
(
    id          int,
    task_id     int,
    test_name   string,
    test_result string
);
```

And dataset populated on this table looks like this.

```
insert into result
values (1, 1, 'test_a', 'pass'),
       (2, 1, 'test_b', 'fail'),
       (3, 1, 'test_c', 'pass'),
       (4, 1, 'test_d', 'pass'),
       (5, 2, 'test_a', 'pass'),
       (6, 2, 'test_b', 'pass'),
       (7, 2, 'test_c', 'pass'),
       (8, 2, 'test_d', 'pass');
```

Basically single task has multiple test results entry. I want to retrieve task_id that has test_b fail but all the other  test passed. So in this  example it should return only task_id: 1.

I've tried with EXISTS and HAVING but it doesn't seem working in this case. I'm new to SQL.  How can I implement it?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just use aggregation with a `having` clause:

```
select task_id
from result
group by task_id
having sum(case when test_name = 'test_b' and test_result = 'fail' then 1 else 0 end) = 1 and
       sum(case when test_result = 'pass' then 1 else 0 end) = count(*) - 1;
```

The first condition validates that test_b failed.  The second counts the number of passes and it should be one less then the number of rows for the task.

If your database supports `except` (or `minus`), you an use set-based operations:

```
select task_id
from result
where test_name = 'test_b' and test_result = 'fail'
except
select task_id
from result
where test_name <> 'test_b' and test_result = 'fail'
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe selecting distinct task IDs that have a fail result:

```
select distinct [task_id], [task_result]
from [result]
where [task_result] = 'fail'
```

Note that this query will scan the entire table unless there is an index on `task_result`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `(task_id, task_name)` is a unique key of your table, you can indeed use `(not) exists`, along with a correlated subqueries wich ensures that other records having the same `task_id` did not passed.

```
select task_id
from result r
where 
    test_name = 'test_b' 
    and test_result = 'fail'
    and not exists (
        select 1 
        from result r1
        where 
            r1.task_id = r.task_id
            and r1.id != r.id
            and r1.test_result = 'fail'
    )
```

The `left join` antipattern also comes to mind:

```
select r.task_id
from result r
left join result r1
    on  r1.task_id = r.task_id
    and r1.id != r.id
    and r1.test_result = 'fail'
where 
    r.test_name = 'test_b' 
    and r.test_result = 'fail'
    and r1.id is null
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b305a898a82e9b9142870e2673051ac8)** - Both queries return:

```
| task_id |
| :------ |
|       1 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code first sums test takers per task and counts fro 'test_b' whether it failed or not. Outer select ensure 'test_b' failed and other have passed.

```
select task_id from (
    select 
    task_id,
    count(test_result) numberoftakers,
    sum(case when test_result<>'pass' AND test_name='test_b' then 1 else 0 end) numberoffailb,
    sum(case when test_result='pass' then 1 else 0 end) numberofallpasses
from result
group by task_id) a
where numberoftakers=numberoffailb+numberofallpasses and numberoffailb=1
```